# Handling apollo-graphql numbered pagination cache

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-client

If I have two routes,

`/posts?page=1`

`/posts/write`

Let's assume

- Each page has 5 posts.
- Visit `/posts?page=1` Then `[post10, post9, post8, post7, post6]` will be saved in Apollo cache.
- Visit `/posts?page=2` Then `[post5, post4, post3, post2, post1]` will be saved in Apollo cache.

In this situation, if I create new post with router `/posts/write`, How do I update cache properly?

**Case 1**

If I visit `page=1` only, 5 posts stored in cache. I can manually update cache to `[new post, post10, post9, post8, post7]`. and then I move url to `page2`, page2 will show `[post6, post5, post4, post3, post2]` correctly. because there is no page2 cache and it will be served from server data.

**Case 2**

If I visit `page=1` and then `page=2`, 10 posts stored in cache. If I manually update like case 1, the `page2` will show `[post5, post4, post3, post2, post1]` which are the **`post6`** disappeared. And futhermore, I cannot assum user visit page1, page2 in sequence. How about user access the url `page1 ===> page4` situation?

How do I avoid this problem? I think there already exist solutions... Anyone can help?

Comment: why operate on cache?    new post = mutation > insert done ON SERVER .. query refresh rereads data from server updating cache with result (array of item ids [by query]  and items [by id] - normalization)

Comment: You might want to update the cache manually because it is faster (it saves a round-trip) and with `optimisticResponse` you get optimistic UI for free if you have written a manual cache update.